# Capturing click outside of a absolute positioned div

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mousedown

http://jsfiddle.net/dgjJe/1/

In the above jsfiddle I am trying to capture when the user clicks outside of the .inner div but I can't seem to get it working.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).mousedown(function (e) {
    var div = $(".inner");
    if (div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        alert('clicked outside of .inner');
    }
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.outer { width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid #000; position:relative; }
.inner { width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid #000; position:absolute; top:25px; left:25px; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`div` variable in your code refers to the `.inner` element, so it doesn't have `.inner` child element. Based on the structure of markup, `has` method is not useful here. You can use `is` method:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    if ( !$(e.target).is('.inner') ) {
        alert('clicked outside of .inner');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MJmPF/

The above method doesn't work if the `.inner` has children elements, for this case you can use `closest` method:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
    if ( !$(e.target).closest('.inner').length ) {
        alert('clicked outside of .inner');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wHpa8/

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) / [$.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) (depending on your jQuery version) to listen for the `mousedown` event on the outer `div` while preventing the inner div from reacting to the `mousedown` event using [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) like so:

```
$('.inner').on('mousedown', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
});
$('.outer').on('mousedown', function(){
    alert('outer');
    return false;
});
```

**[Update Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dgjJe/9/)**

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).mousedown(function (e) {
    var div = $(".inner");
    if (!$(e.target).is('.inner') && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        console.log('clicked outside of .inner');
    }
});
```